# Issue with ADsOpenObject() remote connection and the WinNT provider

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, adsi

I have a problem getting an IADsContainer object from ADsOpenObject() by using the WinNT provider from a service on a remote machine.

I've been able to get the code working in the following scenarios except number 4

1. My application is deployed on the same machine to which it connects(localhost).
2. My application is deployed as a Local Service on the same machine to which it connects(localhost).
3. My application is deployed on a remote machine and it connects by providing an IP.
4. My application is deployed on a remote machine as a Local Service and it connects by providing an IP.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <Adshlp.h>
#include <comdef.h>

IADsContainer* container = nullptr;
HRESULT hres = ADsOpenObject( L"WinNT://192.168.1.30", L"Administrator", L"someAdminPass", ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION | ADS_READONLY_SERVER, IID_IADsContainer, (void**)&container );

if( SUCCEEDED(hres) )
{
    // do stuff with the container object
}
else
{
    _com_error err( hres );
    LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
    std::wcout << errMsg;
}
```

I expect hres to be S_OK and valid 'container' pointer but I only get E_FAIL with error string "Unspecified error"

Comment: `S_FALSE` is a success code. How and where did you get the *"error string 'Unspecified error'"*?

Comment: Does the "myUser" contain the domain name, [ADsOpenObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/adshlp/nf-adshlp-adsopenobject#parameters) says: **This string should always be in the format "<domain>/<user name>" to avoid ambiguity.**

Comment: as @IInspectable says, `SUCCEEDED(S_FALSE )` = true. Provide the real error information, or real code.

Comment: I'm sorry for the S_FALSE confusion. The value is E_FAIL, I did some wrong copy/paste... I've also updated the connection string to how exactly I use it. I don't specify username and it should not be needed, because I use the 'container' object to fetch different user's info.

@DrakeWu-MSFT The error string is fetched as showed in the else case by using the _com_error object.

Comment: I meant I don't specify username in the WinNT:// connection string. :)

Comment: I meant the 2nd parameter of `ADsOpenObject`, and I cannot produce this issue on mine.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Ah sorry. No it does not contain a domain name. I've edited the question with the exact parameters I use, except the password.

Comment: I've just added a domain name to the user name as "Administrator@DOMAIN.com" and it worked!!! Thanks a lot @DrakeWu-MSFT! I don't know how I didn't came to that earlier. For the others reading the comment, beware that the "DOMAIN.COM" part is setup specific.

I will now answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved thanks to the guides in the comments from @DrakeWu-MSFT!

I just needed to specify a FQDN username. If your machine domain is "DOMAIN.COM' then the username string should be "UserName@DOMAIN.com". This solved the issue for me. Also big "thanks" to MS for such a descriptive error message... :)

The main code line now looks like this:

```cpp
HRESULT hres = ADsOpenObject( L"WinNT://192.168.1.30", L"Administrator@MYDOMAIN.COM", L"someAdminPass", ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION | ADS_READONLY_SERVER, IID_IADsContainer, (void**)&container );
```

P.S. Beware that there are other WinAPI functions that don't like FQDN username.